# How do you make the $mdDialog.prompt()'s field to be required

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

Here's their demo script. How do I require that the field be required?

```
var confirm = $mdDialog.prompt()
  .title('What would you name your dog?')
  .textContent('Bowser is a common name.')
  .placeholder('Dog name')
  .ariaLabel('Dog name')
  .initialValue('Buddy')
  .targetEvent(ev)
  .ok('Okay!')
  .cancel('I\'m a cat person');

$mdDialog.show(confirm).then(function(result) {
  $scope.status = 'You decided to name your dog ' + result + '.';
}, function() {
  $scope.status = 'You didn\'t name your dog.';
});
```

Currently, you can enter an empty field and then confirm the prompt, causing the dialog to close and the success function to be provoked with an undefined result value

Ideally, I'd like an error message to appear and the dialog to remain open when an empty field exists.

I'm sure I can achieve this with a custom dialog, but was hoping there was an easy setting that I'm missing

Comment: I looked into this and it would take quite a bit of manipulation of the promt dialog and ultimately it would be cleaner to use a custom dialog.

Answer (score 4):

I ran across this and as of Angular Material [1.1.5](https://github.com/angular/material/blob/v1.1.5/CHANGELOG.md) there is a new required option in the prompt chain that addresses this. The reference docs haven't been updated yet, but the demos show the usage:

```
var confirm = $mdDialog.prompt()
  .title('What would you name your dog?')
  .textContent('Bowser is a common name.')
  .placeholder('Dog name')
  .ariaLabel('Dog name')
  .initialValue('Buddy')
  .targetEvent(ev)
  .required(true) // <---- New required option
  .ok('Okay!')
  .cancel('I\'m a cat person');
```

Comment: is it possible to set a maxlength to the inputfield?

Comment: You will probably need to use $mdDialog.show with your own template if you need additional customization options. $mdDialog.prompt has limited options at this time.

Answer (score 1):

Only solution i know it's to create a **custom template for mdDialog** component.

```
$scope.showPrompt = function(user) {
$mdDialog.show({
    templateUrl: 'app/views/your-dialog.tpl.html',
    locals: {
        callback: $scope.yourFunction // create the function  $scope.yourFunction = function (yourVariable) {
    },
    controller:  function ($scope, $mdDialog, callback) {
        $scope.dialog.title = 'Your title';
        $scope.dialog.abort = function () {
            $mdDialog.hide();
        };
        $scope.dialog.hide = function () {

            if ($scope.Dialog.$valid){
                $mdDialog.hide();
                callback($scope.yourReturnValue, likes the return of input field);
            }
        };
    },
    controllerAs: 'dialog',
    bindToController: true,
    clickOutsideToClose: true,
    escapeToClose: true
});
```

};

Answer (score 0):

you can check here

```
 $mdDialog.show(confirm).then(function(result) {
   if(result!=undefined)
     {
       $scope.status = 'You decided to name your dog ' + result + '.';
    }else
    {
      alert("Wrong Input Enter ");
    }

}
```

Read documentation here
https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/service/$mdDialog

Comment: From the question - "Ideally, I'd like an error message to appear and the dialog to remain open when an empty field exists."

Comment: Unforturnately, by the time the then(function()) is called, the dialog is already closed